# Why is the expanded usercard not breaking the last line?

Tags: bug, profile-page, user-card

I respected the two space/line-break, but it doesn't work at the last line. I mean, `fun -> codewars.com/users/Pankwood` should be in another line.
I've tried two spaces, `<br>`, and `<br />` unsuccessfully.

**Expanded UserCard**

> [image]

**About me**

> [image]

Comment: I’m pretty sure it doesn’t respect line breaks *at all*. It just so happens that your other lines are long enough they  cause wrapping where you want.

Comment: It's weird. The line break works perfectly in the other lines. The problem is just the last one.